# How to generate "action" method for <form> tag builder in in ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The built-in [FormTagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/FormTagHelper.cs) supports "asp-action", "asp-controller", "asp-route" and other attributes. They work fine. But I don't want to manually specify their values for each form. Is it possible to automatically generate "action" attribute based on the current page URL?

After looking at implementation of FormTagHelper I see it uses IHtmlGenerator. When I manually invoke `IHtmlGenerator.GenerateForm(this.ViewContext, null,null,null,"post", null)` in my view, then it works just great. The form is generated automatically with a valid "action" method (including query string). But can I get the same result with  element?

According to this implementation I need the following line of code to be invoked in FormTagBuilder. But with "action" and "controller" set to null

```
tagBuilder = Generator.GenerateForm(
                        ViewContext,
                        Action,
                        Controller,
                        Fragment,
                        routeValues,
                        method: null,
                        htmlAttributes: null);
```

But not sure how to do it

P.S. If I specify `asp-route=""`, then it generates "action" element but it doesn't include query string of the current page.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `asp-all-route-data="@null"` will work. It looks ugly but it works.

I hope there could be a cleaner solution

Comment: Wow - I can't believe that this works and it's what we have to use :(

Comment: BTW/FYI - the querystring params are lost if you add a asp-handler.

Comment: OK - 3rd comment (is there a badge for this?) - you can just use asp-handler="" and it'll generate the action, but again will replace the querystring if there is one. Otherwise it's just a simple action